# Change display of MUI select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the select to display the names when selected instead of the values. To send the values to backend but display the names when selected.

```
    const names = [
      {'name': 'Oliver Hansen', 'id': 12},
      {'name': 'Van Henry', 'id': 13},
      {'name': 'Ralph Hubbard', 'id': 14},
      {'name': 'April Tucker', 'id': 15},
      {'name': 'Omar Alexander', 'id': 16},
      {'name': 'Carlos Abbott', 'id': 17},
      {'name': 'Miriam Wagner', 'id': 18},
      {'name': 'Bradley Wilkerson', 'id': 19},
      {'name': 'Virginia Andrews', 'id': 20},
      {'name': 'Kelly Snyder', 'id': 21},
    ];
    
    export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
      const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
    
      const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {
          target: { value },
        } = event;
        setPersonName(
          // On autofill we get a stringified value.
          typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
              id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
              multiple
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
              renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {names.map((name) => (
                <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name.id}>
                  <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name.id) > -1} />
                  <ListItemText primary={name.name} />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[I want it to display the names instead of the ids when selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11HO1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I added the comment above, because I could not see where `FormControl`, `Select` etc. came from, but I see from the title that they are from MaterialUI. Maybe it is still better for clarity to leave the `import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Select>` will send the selected `id` to the event, not the name.

What I recommend you is to find the value in the array and set its name attribute as the person's name like this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { target: { value } } = event;

    // On autofill we get a stringified value.
    const cleanedVal = typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value;

    const selectedPerson = names.find(name => name.id === cleanedVal);
    setPersonName(selectedPerson.name);
  };
```